# deserialize returns null objects c#

Tags: c#, serialization

When I try to deserialize below XML I get error: Settings xmlns='' was not expected. 
I have mapped the root node in my class below, why do I get that error?

my xml:

```
<Settings>  
    <Access>
        <Phone hasTextField="true">
           <Item description="CMS" />
        </Phone>
    </Access>
</Settings>
```

class
Settings.cs:

```
[XmlRoot("Settings")]
public class AccessNodes
{
    [XmlElement("Access")]
    public Access AccessList { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("Access")]
public class Access
{
  [XmlElement("Phone")]
  public AccessItem Phone { get; set; }
}

public class AccessItem
{
  public AccessItem()
  {
     Items = new List<Item>();
  }

  [XmlAttribute("hasTextField")]
  public bool HasTextField { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("Item")]
  public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

}

```
[XmlType("Item")]
public class Item
{
 [XmlAttribute("description")]
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

SettingsReader.cs

```
public static class SettingsReader<T>
    {
        public static T Deserialize(string basePath)
        {
            string filename = basePath + ".xml";
            T t = default(T);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                t = (T)xs.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            return t;
    }
```

Call to SettingsReader.cs

```
Access access = SettingsReader<Access>.Deserialize(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/access"));
```

Comment: Can you post your deserialization code?

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works for me...

Comment: Please show us **the full error message**, not just a few words you picked out of it.

Comment: This the exact error message: <Settings xmlns=''> was not expected.

Comment: @Jon, I added my code to read the xml, do you now get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize the wrong element - you're trying to deserialize the `Access` type, whereas your top node is `Settings`, which is the name applied to the `AccessNodes` type.

Try this instead:

```
AccessNodes settings = SettingsReader<AccessNodes>.Deserialize(...);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.